# C++ would it be a bad design to inherit (public) classes that has no destructor

Tags: c++, destructor

Would it be a bad design, that a child class inherit a parent class that has no destructor (only the default generated by compiler) ? Some books claimed it's not good, but didn't mention under what situation it would.

Comment: It depends on what's the intent of that inheritance. If you'll never delete a pointer to the base class, then there's no problem(there are some situations in which this will never happen).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deleting an object of a derived type through a pointer to a base type with no virtual destructor is **undefined behavior**. If you expect to do this, and so in general if you expect your class to be extended, you should provide a `virtual` destructor.

```
 struct A
 {};
 struct B : A
 {}

 //...
 A* a = new B;
 delete a;       //undefined behaviour
```

Comment: Lol, who the hell is downvoting every answer? xD

Comment: @BenVoigt you're right, reading back the first answer, it did have some errors.

Comment: @BenVoigt actually, it's not the polymorphic objects that makes this legal, but the fact that it has no virtual destructor.

Comment: @BenVoigt It can be polymorphic with no virtual destructor and still lead to UB.

Comment: @Luchian: I think the new wording for the second sentence covers that, no?  Anyway, your latest fix is good.  +1

Comment: But I don't agree that every class that's meant to be extended should also enable polymorphic deletion.

Comment: @BenVoigt of course not, but then you should **explicitly disallow** polymorphic deletion. Mark delete private in the base class, not rely on good faith :). But then it gets way beyond the scope of the question. And I myself usually follow this rule.

Comment: Here's the relevant quote from the standard: "§5.3.5/3: In the first alternative (delete object), if the static type of the operand is different from its dynamic type, the static type shall be a base class of the operand’s dynamic type and the static type shall have a virtual destructor or the behavior is undefined."

Comment: @EdwardLoper thanks! feel free to edit the answer if you want.

Answer (score 1):

As asked, there's probably no problem at all with this, no. But your subject line says "destructor" and your question says "constructor", so I'm not sure which you meant. If a base class has no virtual destructor, that can be a problem -- the base class destructor could end up not being called. So if the class has any non-POD data members, then those might not be destructed properly in a child class.

Comment: That's a typo, thanks for mention that, I've updated my question

Comment: @warl0ck this is a great minimization of the problem. This can lead to undefined behavior, not just a destructor not being called.

Answer (score 1):

It is best to set destructor as virtual because you then don't have to worry about it in the future.

Inheriting from a class that has no destructor will cause undefined behavior when you delete the class polymorphically and your class destructor will not run.

The only reason I can think of where you wouldn't want your destructor as virtual is when you don't want a vtable created for that function.

Comment: Your second paragraph is wrong. Deleting a pointer to the base class will cause UB, not just inheriting.

Comment: You got it wrong though - "Inheriting from a class that has no destructor will cause undefined behavior" - wrong. See my answer for clarifications.

Comment: You did mention it, but what you said is not correct. Luchian is right.

Comment: You only get undefined behavior if you delete polymorphically... and polymorphic deletion is fairly unusual.

Comment: That is what I meant originally, sorry for the misunderstanding.
I edited my post to clear it up.

Comment: This still isn't accurate.  Only polymorphic deletion would be UB.